# What format is used for xml-serialization of numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

When I write:

```
var d = 12.34D;
d.ToString();
```

it gives `"12,34"`, but when I serialize object with double field, it gives `"12.34"`

It is because `XmlSerializer` uses some specific format/culture? What exactly? I've looked into Double's source code but not seen implementation of `IXmlSerializable`.
Thanks.

Comment: It is the culture/format is at where you say *it gives...*, not in the XmlSerializer.

Comment: The thing is you are comparing a localized representation with a serialized representation. I think that the serializer uses some sort of invariant culture to serialize the data as it should be deserializable on any machine.

Comment: XML serialization uses the invariant culture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `XmlSerializerWriter` uses `XmlConvert.ToString` to convert the values.

The relevant part from that class is [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlConvert.cs,733):

```
return value.ToString("R", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

So it uses the invariant culture, which happens to output the string that is conforming to the XML RFC (So a period as decimal separator).

Format specifier `"R"` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#RFormatString):

> The round-trip ("R") format specifier attempts to ensure that a numeric value that is converted to a string is parsed back into the same numeric value. This format is supported only for the Single, Double, and BigInteger types.

It means that the other end will produce the same `double` result when deserializing the string value.